# BIO Format (Skills,Qualification,Experience)

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have Dataset (CSV format).
[image]

My mail goal is to do named entity recognition and use algorithms that are today's SOTA, for example according to the website nlpprogress.com.

One of the SOTA is this repository: https://github.com/ZihanWangKi/CrossWeigh/tree/master

Now, from what I've seen for named entity recognition I need to create a BIO file format.

Which I don't have right now.

What I have in my hand is a csv with a division of fields into their respective headers.

The question is how do I create such a dataset with the appropriate tags:
B-Skill, I-SKILL, B-EDU, I-EDU, B-EXP, I-EXP

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually annotate a large sample of your input text like this:

```
Irrelevant   O
information, O
Adaptable    B-Skill
to           I-Skill
stuff        I-Skill
,            O
Leadership   B-Skill
skills       I-Skill
...          O
```

But normally NER is intended for unstructured text. So if you consider that the CSV structure is reliable, then there's no point using NER since you already know which text belongs to which category: everything in the 'skills' columns belongs to SKILLS, everything in 'experience' belongs to EXPERIENCE, etc.

Comment: Any idea how do I annotate the BIO tagging with the help of a NLP algorithm? I want to annotate in the same way as shown in your answer. I have thousands of words and manual annotation is out of the question!

Comment: This format (or its [variants](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116518/ner-what-advantage-does-io-format-have-over-bio-format/116523#116523)) is the standard output for NER. NER is supervised, so one trains a model with data manually annotated with BIO, otherwise the data is likely to have errors and so the model would do a lot of errors (and its evaluation would be completely biased). There are of course pretrained model which can be applied directly to raw text, but they can find only the entities that they have been trained to recognize (usually person names, places, etc.)

Comment: So if you find a model which has been trained to find skills, experience etc., then you can apply it directly to your data and you will obtain this kind of output. In my opinion It would not be correct to train a new model on data automatically annotated, since there can be errors.

Comment: Actually I don't want a NER model. I am aware of it. What I meant when I said I want the same output is that I want a model which can label raw text with BIO format. Not the entities. So the output should be the same as above but only the BIO tagging should be there...not the entities

Comment: I'm confused... it seems that you want some random sequence of BIO format as output, but I probably misunderstand :)

Comment: I am sorry. I already have an NER model that I have fine tuned on my own dataset. What I want is a model which can label the entities extracted in the BIO format.

Comment: @spectre do you mean that your model predicts entities in BIO format and you want to convert the output from BIO to something else?  Or do you mean that you don't have any output in BIO format? (if so, it depends on which library you're using but there's certainly an option)

Comment: The output I am getting are the entities. Now I want to label them in the BIO format. Are there any models/libraries for this purpose?

Comment: @spectre ok so this is probably a technical issue with the software, because your NER model is very likely to predict in the BIO format before returning the output as entities. Presumably the authors of the software/library think that the output is more convenient like this. So the question is whether the BIO format can be accessed with the library/software that you're using, possibly with an option. If it's not possible with this software, I'd say it's best to switch to a more standard one.

Comment: do you have any idea of a software/library which can do this?

Comment: @spectre of course, virtually every NER library works with BIO under the hood and I would expect that most of them can give it as output. The ones I know are a bit old and maybe not very convenient, like [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/), [Wapiti](https://wapiti.limsi.fr/), ... But apparently more recent libs can do this too: [Spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020517/how-to-convert-combined-spacy-ner-tags-to-bio-format) can convert the output to BIO for instance (actually a variant of BIO,  BILUO).